smoothly resize container divs on bootstrap carousel instead of the instant "jump" to new size

I am trying to get the container divs to smoothly resize as you go through image or video assets of various sizes/heights in a bootstrap carousel.

right now it "jumps" to resize to the next image size height which doesnt look very nice, and a bit janky.
i can't seem to get it to work. i've tried using % sizing, using vh vw, i also thought there was an action called "transiton/ease" that might help but i'm unable to figure this out so far. any help appreciated.

the content resizing seems mostly ok when an image/video is more wide. but if a image/video asset is tall is it possible of it to resize proportionalty then too or you have to choose one or the other? tall images get cut off right now if browser is made shorter but it would be great if shorter browser made the asset scale down still (without being cut off)

Current code:


$(document).ready(function() {
  function adjustContainerSize() {
    $('.responsive-container').each(function() {
      var maxWidth = $(this).parent().width();
      var maxHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9; // 90% of viewport height
      $(this).css({
        'max-width': maxWidth,
        'max-height': maxHeight
      });
    });
  }

  adjustContainerSize();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustContainerSize();
  });
});
body {
  background-color: violet;
  margin: 0;
  /* Reset margin to 0 */
  padding: 0;
  /* Reset padding to 0 */
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b9dbe5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  text-align: center;
  /* Center images horizontally */
}

.slideshow-container img,
.slideshow-container iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}


/* Show arrows only on hover */

.slideshow-container:hover .prev,
.slideshow-container:hover .next {
  display: block;
}

.prev,
.next {
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
  /* Change cursor to default */
  z-index: 1000;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
  color: silver;
  /* Change color on hover */
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev.disabled,
.next.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Responsive YouTube Video */

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (iframe video) */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  /* Center the video */
  background-color: #b1e1af;
  /* light green */
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Responsive container dimensions */

.responsive-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
}


/* Media queries for different viewport sizes */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 750px;
    max-height: 600px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 970px;
    max-height: 700px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    max-height: 800px;
  }
}
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel slide responsive-container" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?cat">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?dog">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?shark" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 700px;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?tree" alt="Tree Image">
      </div>
      <!-- Video Slide -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="slideshow-container carousel slide responsive-container" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="800">
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?forest" alt="Forest Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?mountain" alt="Mountain Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?animal" alt="Animal Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?building" alt="Building Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?car" alt="Car Image">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel3" class="slideshow-container carousel slide responsive-container" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?sunset" alt="Sunset Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?sky" alt="Sky Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?cloud" alt="Cloud Image">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?moon" alt="Moon Image">
      </div>
      <!-- Video Slide -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




The issue you’re facing is due to the fact that the height of the carousel changes instantly when the active item changes. This causes the “jumping” effect you’re seeing. You can use CSS Transitions to make this more smoother.
HTML/CSS:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Multiple Responsive Slideshows</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  background-color: violet;
  margin: 0; /* Reset margin to 0 */
  padding: 0; /* Reset padding to 0 */
}
.container {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b9dbe5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease; /* Smooth transition for height */
}
.carousel-item {
  text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
}
.slideshow-container img,
.slideshow-container iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
/* Show arrows only on hover */
.slideshow-container:hover .prev,
.slideshow-container:hover .next {
  display: block;
}
.prev, .next {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer; /* Change cursor to pointer */
  z-index: 1000;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
  color: silver; /* Change color on hover */
}
.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.next {
  right: 0;
}
.prev.disabled, .next.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
/* Responsive YouTube Video */
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (iframe video) */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto; /* Center the video */
  background-color: #b1e1af; /* light green */
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Responsive container dimensions */
.responsive-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
}
/* Media queries for different viewport sizes */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 750px;
    max-height: 600px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 970px;
    max-height: 700px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .responsive-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    max-height: 800px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel slide responsive-container" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!-- Image Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?cat">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?dog">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x600/?shark" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 700px;">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?tree" alt="Tree Image">
    </div>
    <!-- Video Slide -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
  <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">❮</a>
  <a class="next" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">❯</a>
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript for responsive container -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  function adjustContainerSize() {
    $('.responsive-container').each(function() {
      var maxWidth = $(this).parent().width();
      var maxHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9; // 90% of viewport height
      $(this).css({'max-width': maxWidth, 'max-height': maxHeight});
    });
  }
  adjustContainerSize();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustContainerSize();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

I’ve added a transition property to the .slideshow-container class for a smooth resizing effect. I also changed the cursor to a pointer for the navigation arrows when they are displayed as a little ouch to make the visual experience a little better.
If that does not work, I have posted some JS code below which adjusts the height of the .slideshow-container to match the height of the currently active carousel item.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to adjust the height of the container
  function adjustContainerHeight() {
    // Get the height of the active item
    var activeItemHeight = $('.carousel-item.active').height();
    // Animate the height of the slideshow container
    $('.slideshow-container').animate({
      height: activeItemHeight
    }, 500); // Transition duration
  }

  // Adjust the container height when the carousel item changes
  $('#myCarousel1').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    adjustContainerHeight();
  });

  // Adjust the container height when the window is resized
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustContainerHeight();
  });

  // Initial adjustment
  adjustContainerHeight();
});


thanks again! the hand symbol is a nice touch. though sadly i just tried this and the transitions don't work. not sure why.

Thanks for letting me know of this. I'm looking into another solution that could fix this. I also submitted an edit to this post. Just so you're aware.

@hellofromlondon I have added a second solution to the answer, which uses a different approach, and uses JS to do the transitions.

@hellofromlondon I hope this revamp of my answer helps.

thanks for helping on so many of my questions. sadly both of those did not work for me. in one case the carousel stoped working. in the other, the jumping between the slides remained. thank you thought, apprecaite the effort.

No problem. I will try to see if I can find another solution, as those were the only ones on the top of my head.

I have tried a few other ways, and this seems to work. But let me know if there are any issues.
Add a CSS transition to the .responsive-container class. This will make changes to the max-width and max-height properties animate smoothly over a specified duration.
.responsive-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  transition: max-width 0.5s ease, max-height 0.5s ease;
}

In your JavaScript code, instead of directly setting the max-width and max-height properties of the .responsive-container elements, you can set their width and height properties.
$(document).ready(function() {
  function adjustContainerSize() {
    $('.responsive-container').each(function() {
      var maxWidth = $(this).parent().width();
      var maxHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9; // 90% of viewport height
      $(this).css({
        'width': maxWidth,
        'height': maxHeight
      });
    });
  }

  adjustContainerSize();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustContainerSize();
  });
});

